# How to call an element in jquery when the ID of the element is stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Template

```
{% for question, count, is_follow in zipp %}

<div class="border rounded my-2 px-3 py-1" style="box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #2b6dad;">

<p class="fst-normal">
  <small>Tags: </small>
  {% for tag in question.tags.all %}
    <small><a href="{% url 'tag' tag.slug %}" style="text-decoration:none; color:black"><i>{{tag.name}} |</i></a></small>
  {% endfor %}
</p>

<p><a href="{{question.get_absolute_url}}" style="text-decoration: none; color: black"><h5>{{ question.question }}</h5>
<small>Arguments added: {{ count }}</small></a></p>
<div class="blank" id="{{question.question_id}}">
  {% include 'snippets/follow_question.html' %}
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1"><i class="fa fa-share-alt" style="padding-right: 3px;"></i>Share</button>
</div>

{% endfor%}
```

Script

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(event){
  $(document).on('click', '#follow', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var this_element = $(this)
    var pk = $(this_element).attr('value');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{% url 'follow_question' %}',
      data: {'id': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function(response){
        var id = $(this_element).closest('.blank').attr('id');
        $('id').html(response['form']);
      },
      error: function(rs, e){
        console.log(rs.responseText);
      },
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

Inside the script, the ID of the element is stored in var id. I want to use that ID to change its html as I was trying to do in the next line but it's not working. How can I do that?

Comment: Simply built an id selector with the content of `id`. No black magic, only string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for an associated element to get it's id to use to look for that same element again.

That is redundant when you can just use the reference to the closest element itself

Simplified version:

```
this_element.closest('.blank').html(response['form'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
var id = $(this_element).closest('.blank').attr('id');
$(`#${id}`).html(response['form']); // $('#' + id)
```